# How to get Memory information from QNX using c program?

Tags: c, ubuntu, qnx

I have written a code which perfectly works on Ubuntu . But getting unexpected behavior on QNX .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
  {

    printf( "Total Memory  = %ld MB\n",
    (sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES)* sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE))/1048576);

    printf("Getting available memory...\n");
    printf( "Available     = %ld MB\n",
    (sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES)* sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE))/1048576);

    printf("Getting used memory...\n");
    printf( "Used Memory   = %ld MB\n",((sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES) - 
    sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES))* sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE))/1048576);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This perfectly works fine on Ubuntu but not on QNX .
Is there any different way out to do this ?

Output :

```
     Total Memory = - 3906 MB

     Available    = - 3096 MB

     Used Memory  =  0 MB
```

Comment: What unexpected behaviour? Add a description of problem.

Comment: @ Lps updated . 3906 is the page size actually .

Comment: @sourav Ghosh not sure .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investing lot of time i got a way i could do it.

Using:

```
Showmem -S
```

To execute this command from c Programming Language use pipe

```
FILE *fp;
pf = popen(command,"r");
```

Then you can grab the data from fp.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing on the [QNX doco page for `sysconf`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fsysconf.html) about either `_SC_PHYS_PAGES` nor `_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES` but it does have the note:

> The requested configurable system limit. If name isn't defined for the system, -1 is returned.

So, it's possible that that information is not actually made available by QNX.

You could verify this by printing out `sysconf(oneOfThoseTwo)` directly and seeing if you get `-1`.

If you *do* get back a decent value then it may be related to arithmetic overflow, in which case you could restructure your calculation to avoid it:

```
#define MEG 1048576
(sysconf(oneOfThoseTwo) + MEG - 1) / MEG) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)
```